# How to style a layer

Tags: openlayers-5

I am trying to put image icons on my nodes in an openlayers 5 layer, but can't seem to get it right.
I load an osm file and everything is ok, but i get a small circle instead of the icon.

I've searched online and all i can find is how to change a feature icon, not all features of a layer.

Part of my osm file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version='0.6' upload='false' generator='JOSM'>
  <node id='-102236' lat='37.1556611' lon='-8.5700716'>
    <tag k='vpa_cod' v='784' />
    <tag k='vpa_linha' v='11,38,' />
  </node>
</osm>
```

Declaration of layer

```
new VectorLayer({
          source: new VectorSource({
            url: './assets/layers/111_.osm',
            format: new OSMXML(),
            formatOptions: {
                extractStyles: true,
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2
                },

                style: new Style({
                  image: new Icon( ({
                    anchor: [0, 0],
                    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                    src: 'assets/images/icons/11.svg',
                    scale : 0.35
                  }))
                })
          })
        })
```

I want to have an icon on my nodes, but only get small circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style should be a property of the layer, not the source

```
new VectorLayer({
          source: new VectorSource({
            url: './assets/layers/111_.osm',
            format: new OSMXML(),
            formatOptions: {
                extractStyles: true,
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2
            }
          }),
          style: new Style({
            image: new Icon({
              anchor: [0, 0],
              anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
              anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
              src: 'assets/images/icons/11.svg',
              scale : 0.35
            })
          })
        })
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it was really easy after all.